# Android USB Driver for Windows 7?

Tags: android

On http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html android Developers lists the instructions for installing their USB drivers for Windows Vista and Windows XP.  But **Windows' current OS in Windows 7** -  where are are the instructions for that?   (FWIW I'm using Windows 7 64 bit.  MY Eclipse and Java tools are 32 bit)

BTW, I'm aware that there is lots of 3rd party advice and comment and debate about this all over the web but is there anything official from Android/Google?

I have 2 XP systems which work fine with my Droid Incredible after editing android_winusb.inf .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

To fix the USB driver missing
I had to see what is the real VID and PID of my android device
I edited the windows setup information android_winusb.inf and add a section with the same name & PID & VID.

That is what you have to do with unknown product from China.

Answer (score 2):

If your droid is HTC one, you can download proper USB driver as long as HTC platform sources from http://developer.htc.com/index.html.

USB driver stated under aforementioned link - works well with my Windows 7 x64

Comment: The items at the HTC developer site are all kernel and webkit source.  There are no simple plug & play drivers for HTC Droid Incredible phones there.

Answer (score 2):

The HTC Sync application contains the HTC Incredible Windows 7 Driver.
http://www.htc.com/us/support/droid-incredible-verizon/downloads/

Answer (score 2):

Android usb driver from their can work for most devices but installing the SDK is a pain. AndroidSim.net has a nice package pulled from the SDK ready to install. www.androidsim.net/2009/08/how-to-1-how-to-install-usb-driver-on.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a solution from Google, because the USB drivers are written by HTC.

If you want usb drivers you must instal HTC Sync ( works for me with my Desire on both win7 x86 and x64)

Edit:
The same goes for my Lg Optimus.

And if you read carefully the link you posted, all the devices are "with Google" phones and/or developer phones.

Comment: Now I'm really confused because I DID install the drivers from that page to get my HTC incredible to work on my XP systems.  I had to edit the .inf file.   HTC sync says it's a tool for synchronizing Outlook  - I didn't use it for XP, but that's how it's done for Windows 7?

Comment: I don't know of the method with editing .inf files. But with the sync program it worked for me, because it puts the requiered drivers for adb and all other modes.

Comment: I can confirm i could not get the generic drivers to work on Win7 x64 with my Samsung Galaxy S.  I had to install the drivers provided with the phone (via Kies), so similar to what iliyan did.  This does not mean it isn't possible however, just that i had better things to do than muck around with drivers! ;)

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding you correctly, you're having trouble using usb on windows 7 with eclipse?
You'll need to install motorolas usb drivers, 
http://www.motorola.com/Support/US-EN/Support-Homepage/Software_and_Drivers/USB-and-PC-Charging-Drivers.
If you have google usb drivers installed, after restarting, it will install adb.
If not, just re-run the process to install google's drivers and go from there.